# Should a user be allowed to vote to close a question that he has answered?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close, closed-questions

When someone votes to close a question, he's saying that, in its current form, the question doesn't comply with SO's guidelines for questions and should not (possibly cannot) be answered.

Given that, should a user be allowed to vote to close a question and subsequently provide an answer?

What about the other way around: should a user be allowed to vote to close a question while having answered it?

My suggestion is:

1. (a) Users should be banned from answering questions they have voted to close,

   (b) If the question is re-opened or the user's close vote expires (automatically after 2 days, I believe), then the answer-ban should be lifted.
2. (a) Users should be banned from voting-to-close a question to which they have an answer.

   (b) If the answer is deleted, then the vote-to-close ban should be lifted.

---

After reading the related posts linked by Nine Shogs Shogging, a reasonable alternative is

1. (a) Users should be banned from adding non-wiki answers to questions they have voted to close,

   (b) If the question is re-opened or the user's close vote expires (automatically after 2 days, I believe), then the non-wiki-answer-ban should be lifted.
2. (a) Users should be banned from voting-to-close a question to which they have a non-wiki answer.

   (b) If the answer is deleted or converted to wiki, then the vote-to-close ban should be lifted.

Comment: Related: [Closing Etiquette: Why Do Some Answer *and* Close?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4283/closing-etiquette-why-do-some-answer-and-close), [No reputation for answers on posts you vote to close](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69825/no-reputation-for-answers-on-posts-you-vote-to-close)

Comment: I remember a guy revenge downvoting me once because I called him a hypocrite for answering a question he voted to close (back when we had a "subjective & argumentative" close reason) Ah, good times.

Comment: Please add a rationale for this.  I don't see an actual problem here, just a possible slight inconsistency in behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In many cases I would agree with this, but I'd hate to see it as a blanket rule.  Certainly I don't think it should be answered if:

- It's a duplicate.  If one has an answer, add it to the original.
- It's of obvious unanswerable quality, such as a spam post or other such nonsense.

But there are certainly situations where an answer could be justified:

- It's off-topic and needs to be migrated.  (As Rosinante points out, the answer will be migrated with it.)
- It's off-topic and not migrate-able, but you still have a helpful answer.
- It's in some other way not applicable to Stack Overflow, but you still have a helpful answer.

To that end, I see answering and voting to close as two separate and distinct actions.  (A topic that's been [discussed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105641/148400), but specifically with regards to migrations.)  One need not necessarily affect the other.

- If you have reason to vote to close a question, do so.
- It you have a helpful answer for a user's question, post it.

There are those who may down-vote your answer and claim that you shouldn't have posted it.  And, well, given that this is an open community they're well within their rights to do so.  But as a question and answer site I'm sure the user who asked the question would appreciate the answer.

Now, as I mentioned earlier with regards to unanswerable quality, sometimes it can be downright silly.  Even if you have an answer, there's still the question of whether or not the answer belongs on Stack Overflow.  You may very well have an answer to a ridiculously off-topic question, but the answer doesn't belong here any more than the question does.  But if you have an answer to a low quality, not constructive, or too localized question that's at least a valid *attempt* at a question, by all means post it.

It's entirely subjective based on each individual question.  Which is why I'd hate to see it as a blanket rule.  Sometimes I have an answer and I want to help the user.  Why place a barrier in the way of that?  Many times a question will be close while I'm composing the answer, and I'll end up trying to summarize it in a comment just to be as helpful as I can.  Even that barrier gets in the way of helping users, please don't add more barriers.

Comment: That's a very good perspective to consider. I suppose if the question is closed and doesn't belong, eventually it will be deleted, but in the meantime you've helped someone. I'm sold.

Answer (score 7):

I'll fess up. Sometimes I cover my bets. I'll vote to close, but if I have an answer, I'll answer. After all, if the question migrates, my answer will migrate with it.

And I will confess further. In a few moments of disgust and frustration, I've thought: "This is wildly non-constructive, but I bet it's going to survive. And if it does, why shouldn't I collect cheap rep along with everyone else?" Is that nice of me? Probably not. Is it worth writing code to prevent? I doubt it.

Comment: I admit that my problem is more with "not constructive", "duplicate", and "not real" questions. I see the logic in this for certain "off topic" questions, specifically the ones for which there is an appropriate stackexchange site.

Comment: @Rosinante hehe ive done the same `+1`